# How do I migrate a simple class library using HttpHandler to using the CoreCLR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, portable-class-library, coreclr

I have a library that exposes some request processing functionality using IHttpHandler. I looked, but can't find any information on how to use the new ASP.NET 5 CoreCLR (not the full 4.5 framework) to reimplement this functionality.

Let's say the handler is as simple as the one below.

```
public class TestHttpHandler :IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";

        context.Response.Write("<html><h1>Hello world!</h1></html>");
    }
}
```

Note that I'm actually interested only in making this library truly portable (System.Web doesn't work for profile 259, which my library needs to target), so I want to know what to subclass or implement in order to get this to process requests when run using the CoreCLR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Asp.Net 5 (ASP.NET Core) the Middleware is the replacement for HttpModule/HttpHandler. If you want to implement your middlewares in a class library you have to use the asp.net class library which supports multi framework targeting like .net core.

Learn about Middleware:

[ASP.NET 5 Middleware, Or Where Has My HttpModule Gone?](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/269/asp-net-5-middleware-or-where-has-my-httpmodule-gone)

[Sample Middleware](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/blob/master/samples/Builder.Middleware.Web/Startup.cs)

Comment: Thanks, the second link is most useful. I will build my middleware as a set of convention-based classes and an extension method to easily add it into a pipeline.